# valor da lista a uma variavel, Python

Tags: python, lista

Eu quero criar uma lista, e atribuir a uma variável o valor referente ao posicionamento daquela lista

Por exemplo lista = ["a", "b", "c"]

Vamos supor que o random me dê a letra "c"

Eu quero uma variável n que receba o número 2

Answer (score 2):

vc pode criar uma função que receba a lista e o elemento que vc quer achar que retorne a posição dela.

```
    def ref(lista, elemento):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[i] == elemento:
                return i
        return False

    # exemplo de uso 

    lista = ['a','b','c']
    n = ref(lista,'c')
    print('n =', n)
```

se não achar o elemento ele retorna um False.

Comment: Mas acontece é que eu quero sortear um elemento aleatorio de uma lista, e atribuir o valor dele a uma variavel. Eu quero realmente o valor da posição, nesse exemplo que eu coloquei, eu quero o valor "2" (que é o numero da posição) em uma variavel

Comment: no exemplo que dei vc coloca a lista e coloca o elemento e ele retorna a posição que ele se encontra na lista, se não encontrar ele retorna false. se vc quer um valor aleatório pode importar o random e usar random.choice(lista) dai ele pega um elemento aleatório da lista.
no caso eu coloquei o valor da posição na variável n.

Comment: Listas em Python tem o método `.index` que já faz o que você sugere. Além disso, `for i in range(len...):` e definitivamente pouco idiomático para Python, e não deveria estar presente numa resposta para aconselhar novatos.

Comment: Se houver algo errado com minha resposta me avise que tentarei ajudá-lo da melhor forma possível.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Importa o método choice do módulo random que gera elementos randômicos(aleatórios)

from random import choice

# Cria uma lista

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']              

# utiliza o método random para retornar um elemento aleatório da sua lista

elemento = choice(lista)            

# Utiliza o metódo index dos objetos de tipo list ara retorna o índice do elemento retornado

indice = lista.index(elemento)   

# Imprime o elemento e seu índice

print(elemento, indice)


'''

Esse algoritmo só funciona se sua lista não possuir elementos de mesmo valor 
pois o metódo index dos objetos tipo list retorna
a primeira ocorrência do elemento.

Exemplo:

'''

lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

elemento = 'a'

indice = lista.index(elemento)

print(elemento, indice)

'''

Retorna o índice de valor 0 e não 3 mesmo 'a' aparecendo tanto em indice 0 
como em 3, ou seja o método index retorna a
primeira ocorrência do elemento lembre-se disso

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Um metodo mais facil de você fazer isso é :

```
 l=['nathan','guilherme','otavio','ana']

# Lista que irá receber o indice
lista_enumerada = []

# for com enumerate, para que possamos ver o seu indice
for a,b in enumerate(l):
    lista_enumerada.append(a) # adicionando o valor a(indice) a lista

#armazenamento da escolha randomica
choice = random.randint(0,3)
n = l[choice] # Random na lista principal
print(n)
print(lista_enumerada[choice])
```

Comment: Em vez de `enumerate`, um jeito mais simples de ter a lista de índices é: `lista_enumerada = list(range(len(l)))`

Comment: Valeu! não tinha pensando em utilizar esse metodo do `len` para ter uma lista somente dos indices, aprendi somente a forma do `enumerate`. Isso facilitará nos meus proximos cod's. Muito Obrigado